# How can I know that GOD really loves me?

Tags: love

How can I know that GOD really loves me? Where in the Bible does it say that? I hear preachers always saying this but where can I go and read this and get a full understand that HE loves me and wants a relationship with me....

Comment: This is something you should talk to a church leader or another wise Christian who you trust about.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE, and thanks for taking the site tour. For more on what this site is all about, see: [How we are different than other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1808/20394). I would say your question is a valid one for this site if the main thing you want to know is the biblical basis for the belief that God loves us individually. I've pointed to an already existing question that should help on that question. Meanwhile, I hope you'll browse some of the other questions and answers on this site.

Answer (score 1):

The basic premise that God loves everyone is found in John 3:16

> For God loved the world in this way: He gave his one and only Son, so
>   that everyone who believes in him will not perish but have eternal
>   life.

Going deeper you will find this concept agreed on by everyone who knows Him.

Peter knew the Lord intimately and said,

> "God resists the proud but gives grace to the humble. Humble
>   yourselves, therefore, under the mighty hand of God, so that he may
>   exalt you at the proper time, casting all your cares on him, because
>   he cares about you." (1 Peter 5:6b-7)

These aren't just fuzzy feelings that the Heavenly Father has for us. He actually proves His love by humbling Himself and serving us in many ways.

In Acts 17:25 Paul said that God is not

> served by human hands, as though he needed anything, since he himself
>   gives everyone life and breath and all things.

Jesus said we will truly be like God when we love even our enemies

> For He causes His sun to rise on the evil and the good, and sends
>   rain on the righteous and the unrighteous. (Matthew 5:45)

I think my favorite quote from Paul is,

> But God proves his own love for us in that while we were still
>   sinners, Christ died for us. (Romans 5:8)

The Father of all Creation loves you enough to die for you so His righteousness can become your righteousness. He redeemed us so we can be adopted as sons and daughters. This is why we say He is worthy of *all* the glory and praise. He did the impossible because He loves us.

If you really want to see how God much loves you, simply look at the response of Jesus to everyone who comes to Him. He never turns anyone away who comes to Him humbly (willing to be corrected) and trusting His loving kindness, but heals and forgives every one. In John 5:19 Jesus said,

> Truly I tell you, the Son is not able to do anything on his own, but
>   only what he sees the Father doing. For whatever the Father does, the
>   Son likewise does these things,

meaning He is the very image of God. The gospel of John says that Jesus is the Word of God made flesh.

Look at Jesus. Search the scriptures and you will see that His sacrificial love and forgiveness is always front and center. Even though all people, even God's own people, have committed unspeakable sins, God made a way to forgive that sin by putting all of our punishment on His Son Jesus. That means He can legally dismiss your case!

Three days after He nailed our sin to that cross, He rose from the dead signaling victory over death, hell and the grave. Turn from your sin and put all of your trust in Jesus Christ who loves you and gave Himself for you, and His victory becomes your victory. He promises to give you a new heart and to renew your mind as you come to understand His word by the power of His Holy Spirit who is with everyone who believes. Remain in Him and He will keep His promise to give you everlasting life. Get to know Him through His word and prayer, and I pray that your eyes will be opened to see how much He already loves you!

Answer (score 0):

I agree that you should talk to a pastor or other Christian mentor about, but, you can also see evidence of God's love for you in his actions. Consider John 3:16 - "For God so loved the world that he gave his one and only Son, that whoever believes in him shall not perish but have eternal life.” Not only does this verse say that God loves the world, it stresses the extent of His love, detailing how He gave up His only son for us to live. The entire rest of the Gospel details this concept specifically. Another place you could look is the story of the prodigal son. While this parable from Jesus doesn't directly mention God and people, the father's unconditional love and forgiveness for his son. Finally, in 1 John 4: 8, John writes that "Whoever does not love does not know God, because God is love."